# Add vector drawable for a Button Background

Tags: android, vector

Currently, I have this Button and I want to show a vectorDrawable as its background:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/replace_battery_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/group_28"
        android:text="@string/replace_battery"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>
```

and this vectorDrawable as its background:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="347dp"
    android:height="93dp"
    android:viewportWidth="347"
    android:viewportHeight="93">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:strokeColor="#FFB5B6B7"
        android:strokeWidth="2"
        android:pathData="M5 1.1h106v90H5c-2.2 0-4-1.79-4-4v-82c0-2.2 1.8-4 4-4Z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFBD4448"
        android:pathData="M109 0h233c2.76 0 5 2.24 5 5v82c0 2.76-2.24 5-5 5H109V0Z"/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FF000000"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
        android:pathData="M39.5 30.53c0-3.31 2.69-6 6-6h21c3.31 0 6 2.69 6 6v39.28c0 3.31-2.69 6-6 6h-21c-3.31 0-6-2.69-6-6z"/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFBD4448"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:pathData="M58.45 36.46l-8.8 13.7h12.7l-8.3 13.71"/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FF000000"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:pathData="M52.1 16.4h7.8"/>
</vector>
```

it doesn't show anything as its background, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` as first line of `group_28.xml` file. `group_28.xml` file should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="347dp"
    android:height="93dp"
    android:viewportWidth="347"
    android:viewportHeight="93">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:strokeColor="#FFB5B6B7"
        android:strokeWidth="2"
        android:pathData="M5 1.1h106v90H5c-2.2 0-4-1.79-4-4v-82c0-2.2 1.8-4 4-4Z"/>
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFBD4448"
        android:pathData="M109 0h233c2.76 0 5 2.24 5 5v82c0 2.76-2.24 5-5 5H109V0Z"/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FF000000"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
        android:pathData="M39.5 30.53c0-3.31 2.69-6 6-6h21c3.31 0 6 2.69 6 6v39.28c0 3.31-2.69 6-6 6h-21c-3.31 0-6-2.69-6-6z"/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFBD4448"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:pathData="M58.45 36.46l-8.8 13.7h12.7l-8.3 13.71"/>
    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FF000000"
        android:strokeWidth="4"
        android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round"
        android:pathData="M52.1 16.4h7.8"/>
</vector>
```

After that if still not shows up add `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` instead of Button in your `layout.xml` file.

Comment: it makes no difference

Comment: then use `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` instead of `Button`

Comment: please add this to your answer, I made it accepted